# How do I grant an application Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/dataConnections/read access over a specific database in Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-explorer, azure-sdk

I am trying to grant an application read access to the data connections of a specific database in Kusto. How do I grant this permission to this managed identity? There is not a place within the azure portal to grant this permission at the database level. I am trying to avoid granting this permission at the cluster level. This is the error I am receiving from my app.

```
The client 'id' with object id 'id' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/dataConnections/read' over scope '/subscriptions/subscription/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/cluster/databases/database-foo'
```

I tried going to the azure portal to grant my app this permission, but there is no IAM tab within the database. The cluster does have the IAM tab, but I am avoiding adding the permission there for security reasons.

[No IAM place to add permissions of this type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xe0E.png)
[IAM available in cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxklw.png)

Comment: For _resource administration_ like listing data connections, you can assign role under [**cluster IAM only**](https://i.imgur.com/RmsruK9.png) not under database.  For _data administration_, you can assign role using [Permissions](https://i.imgur.com/DZrADcJ.png) tab under database. Check this MS Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/access-control/role-based-access-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can grant *Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/dataConnections/read* access under **cluster IAM only**, not under specific database in Kusto for **resource** administration like listing data connections.

When I tried to list these data connections by running below REST API call without assigning role, I too got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/{clusterName}/databases/{databaseName}/dataConnections?api-version=2023-08-15
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to assign proper RBAC role like `Reader` under database **cluster** as below:

[image]

When I tried to list these data connections by running below REST API call after assigning role, I got **response** successfully:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/{clusterName}/databases/{databaseName}/dataConnections?api-version=2023-08-15
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Role-based access control in Kusto - Azure Data Explorer | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/access-control/role-based-access-control)

Comment: Thank you! Would definitely love to see IAM permissions at a database level become a feature